# Photoshop Version 23, bounding box for text is invisible

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

With the new version of Photoshop 2022 (version 23) the text bounding box where you can resize text is invisible. This is a screengrab of a selected text box that I can move around but not resize. 100% of my work in Photoshop involves text, and this is going to make it very difficult to work. In searching for answers to this issue it appeared to be an issue in Version 21 and it was fixed in Version 22, but it's back. Is there an option somewhere that I can click to make the bounding box visible and the text editable with the selection tool?

I also have another issue but don't understand why it occurs. 90% of the time when I click on the Text tool, a dashed bounding box will appear where I can resize if it there is overset text. But 10% of the time, when I click on the text tool, the bounding box is also invisible and there is just a straight line, and text just goes on horizontally. When this happens, I have to delete and re-create a rectangular bounding box. Does anyone know why this happens?

Edit: I restarted my computer and I restarted Photoshop and I still have the same problem. Photoshop 2022 Version 23.0.0 Laptop: Macbook Pro 13-inch, 2017, Thunderbolt 3 ports Operating System: macOS Big Sur version 11.5.2

[image: Screengrab of selected text box with invisible bounding box]

Comment: Wellcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Welcome! Could you clarify... are you creating *area type* or *point type*? Area type is where you use the Text Tool to click-drag a box, then type inside the box. Point type is where you simply just click with the text tool and then start typing. I'm really just guessing here, but it sounds like you aren't aware that there is a difference. -- with the type layer highlighted in the Layers Panel, does choosing `Type > Convert To Area/Point Type` from the menu help?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for teaching me about point and area type. I've read up on it now and I understand the difference. 

My first question, however, is still troubling me.  `Type >Convert to area/point type`, still does not make a bounding box appear, and I cannot re-size any text box by dragging anchor points around the outside with the Move tool...because there is no bounding box at all. I reinstalled photoshop, restarted my computer and spent a long time searching forums for similar complaints, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have "Show Transform Controls" box ticked?

[image]

Comment: I am absolutely mortified! I never knew there was even a box there! In all the versions of Photoshop I've ever used it must have been dicked by default. Oh my goodness, how utterly embarrassing. Thank you so much JeffK! I'm going to go hide now.

Comment: No worries. I've often been frustrated by the most simple of issues in Photoshop. :)

Comment: StackExchange is such a NICE community, my goodness. I came here from Reddit, and I can't believe how nice everyone is. I'm learning so much from the forums, and from questions. So just...yeah..thank you so much.